# How to make camera follow object without rotating

Tags: animation, objects, camera

I want the camera to follow someone running without rotating while the arms/body moves if its the child of that part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a Copy Location Constraint on the Camera and set the object to follow as the Target. Check Offset to keep current offset and prevent camera snapping to the object tracked.

[image]

[image]